# Error calling createSheet and trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
String sheetName = "some sheet name";
SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
```

I am trying to execute these code and having those errors, If some body has an idea about the problem:-)

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Sheet to SXSSFSheet  ..  Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() is undefined for the type SXSSFSheet  ... Java Problem

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using?

Comment: Which version of Java and POI are you using? If I remember correctly, POI actually consists of several jars. Please list all your versions.

Comment: I am using poi 3.14 jdk 1.8

Comment: Having mismatches in POI versions can cause these kinds of issues. See the FAQ #1 question: https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html Could you try and run the few lindes of code there?

Comment: In final version of `apache poi 3.14` `SXSSFSheet` has that method. So either you are not using final version of `apache poi 3.14` or there are lower versions of `apache poi` in class path while running. So the class loader uses those lower versions instead of `apache poi 3.14`.